# Adding whitespace in a button in CSS

Tags: css, button

I got a nice landing page built with LeadPages, but can't afford to keep paying for it at the moment. It converts quite well:

```
https://www.anxietysupportnetwork.com/purpose-fairy-landing
```

Anyway, I'm making my own version, which is similar, though not quite the same. I want that button to be the width of the screen to make it super-obvious to click. How would I style my button to appear the same:

https://www.anxietysupportnetwork.com/purpose-fairy/

I'm a novice coder, so please go easy on me! Appreciate your help in advance,

Dan

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of the markup that shows the problem here, not a link to your web site that will change tomorrow helping no one in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the "CLICK HERE – IT’S 100% FREE" button. If you want the button to be the width of the page, try adding `width:100%` to your version in the CSS file. Comment if you need more help.

Comment: That worked. Perfect!

Comment: @Dan If my solution solved your problem, please mark it as the solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

Make changes in your CSS File and Try to add this code hope this works for you!

```
.site-inner, .wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1100px;
    }


   .cubutton {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 99999px;
    background-color: #44ace8;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 2.0rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[code pen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgyZZK)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<style>
.myBtn {
    color: white;
    background-color: #44ace8;
    border-color: #44ace8;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.myBtn:hover {
  color: black;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <a href="#" class="btn myBtn">CLICK HERE – IT’S 100% FREE</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```